# Import module to virtual environment on airflow

Tags: python, virtualenv, airflow, virtual-environment

I have a packaged DAG where I store my module in sub-folder.
I'm using PythonVirtualenvOperator and want to access this module from the virtual env.

The folder system -

```
dags/
    packaged_dag.zip/
        dag.py
        package/
            my_module.py
            __init__.py
```

dag.py

```
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonVirtualenvOperator

def my_function(**kwargs):
    from package import my_module


with models.DAG(
default_args=default_dag_args) as dag:
virtualenv_task = PythonVirtualenvOperator(
    task_id="virtualenv_python",
    python_callable=my_function,
    system_site_packages=True,
    dag=dag,
)
```

For this I will get package module not found.
If I'll move the import to the main dag file (like with PythonVirtualenvOperator) - it will work fine but I want the file from the virtualenv.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
dags/
  folder/
    my_module.py
  main.py
```

main.py

```
default_args = {
    "owner": "airflow"}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='example',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=days_ago(2),
)

def my_module_virtualenv():
    """
    Example function that will be performed in a virtual environment.

    Importing at the module level ensures that it will not attempt to import the
    library before it is installed.
    """
    from dags.folder.my_module import main as my_module
    my_module()

check_database = PythonVirtualenvOperator(
    task_id="my_module",
    python_callable=my_module_virtualenv,
    requirements=["psycopg2-binary==2.8.6"],
    system_site_packages=True,
    dag=dag,
)
```

It's not standard practice since there's no `__init__.py` but it works. `__init__.py` was giving me trouble when I tried to `docker-compose up airflow-init`

Comment: Does this mean you'd need to put all your dags that use this operator into main.py